# Finding the Normal & Tangent Vector and write an Equation.

Tags: calculus

Find a normal vector and a tangent vector at the
point P. Write an equation for the tangent line and an equation
for the normal line.

$x^2 + xy + y^2 = 3; P(−1,−1).$

So what I did first was find the gradient by taking the partial derivatives.

$▽f$ = $(2x+y)i + (x+2y)j$

$▽f$  $(-1,-1)$ = $3i-3j = 3$

Normal Vector $i+j$

Tangent Vector $i-j$

How does one find the tangent line and normal line from this?

Comment: The normal vector is $3i - 3j$, which is not 3! This is the direction of the normal line. Have you seen the vector form of a line?

Comment: I assumed that is how the normal and tangent vector was found by reducing?

Comment: The gradient of a curve is a vector which is normal to the curve. What do you mean by "reducing"?

Comment: $\frac{3i-3j}{3}$ = $i-j$

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

$\vec{r}$ represents the point (could be any points) on the line , and $\vec{x}$ is a known point on the line

$\vec{r}-\vec{x}$ is the direction of the line.

---

P.S : I don't know why I earn a downvote . This is very basic knowledge in elementary geometry ( someone call it analytical geometry) . Therefore , I just provide some hints without details. Thanks to your imprudent judgement , I will keep silent.

Comment: Where did r come from I did not see it as a variable in the problem?

Comment: @LittleJon . If you consider a function $f(x)$ , then the graph of it is a line. i.e every point on the line can be described by its location: $\vec{r} = (x,y)=(x,f(x))$ . Get the point ? It is just a method to deal with the geometric problem.